# Comparing dates when date my be null

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get all dates in a Linq query between `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Both my `StartDate` and `EndDate` are the right dates, but my results are inconsistent. Everything else in the query works, just not the comparison of the dates.  What am I doing wrong?

```
where (startDate == null || DateTime.Compare((DateTime)startDate,
o.FirstAirDate) < 0) && (endDate == null|| DateTime.Compare(
o.FirstAirDate, (DateTime)endDate) > 0)
```

Dates are showing up outside of the range and when I move the dates closer together nothing appears.  For example If I search from December 21-26 I get results between those two dates but also a date for the 27th shows up.  If I search from December 23-26 nothing shows up, even though I saw dates in this range show up when I searched from December 21-26

Comment: @Tgsmith61591, I added a comment about what is not working.  I have been looking at this for a while and am pretty puzzled about what is not working

Comment: Your date range should be inclusive so change it as `where (startDate == null || DateTime.Compare((DateTime)startDate,
o.FirstAirDate) <= 0) && (endDate == null|| DateTime.Compare(
o.FirstAirDate, (DateTime)endDate) >= 0)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to get all instances where `FirstAirDate` is between `startDate` and `endDate` (and either `startDate` or `endDate` can be null) and they are all `DateTime` objects you might want to try something like:

```
var objects = MyObjectsList.Where(o => 
     (!startDate.HasValue || o.FirstAirDate >= startDate.Value) 
  && (!endDate.HasValue || o.FirstAirDate <= endDate.Value))
```

You can compare dates with simple comparison operators, just have to use the `.Value` for the nullable DateTime properties when doing the comparison - in which case it's best to null check first.

Answer (score 2):

Your last inequality:

```
DateTime.Compare(o.FirstAirDate, (DateTime)endDate) > 0
```

is the wrong way. Compared to the first inequality, which looks correct, you can ***either*** swap the two arguments to `Compare`, ***or*** change `< 0` into `> 0`. But you do both, which cancels each other.

It is easier to simply use comparison between `DateTime` values directly, for example:

```
where (startDate == null || (DateTime)startDate < o.FirstAirDate)
  && (endDate == null || o.FirstAirDate < (DateTime)endDate)
```

May I ask, is the declared C# type (compile-time type) of `startDate`, and `endDate`, `object` or `DateTime?` (i.e. `Nullable<DateTime>`). If they are `Nullable<>`, if you dare, you can use negation and *lifted operators* and turn this into:

```
where !(o.FirstAirDate <= startDate) && !(endDate <= o.FirstAirDate)
```

Note that the `null` checks are included here. If an operand to `<=` is `null`, the result is `false`, and because of the negation it will work in the `null` cases because of that.